# Фото товара в деталях заказа woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Не смог найти ответ на такой вопрос в гугле)).
Есть ли возможность добавить фото товара в детали заказа в моем аккаунте? (/my-account/view-order/305/)
И ткните в каком направлении ковырять.
Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит - делали заказа? Какая страница - checkout?

Comment: В моем аккаунте - test.com/my-account/view-order/305/

Answer (score 0):

Вывод деталей заказа производится в шаблоне

`/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/order/order-details-item.php`.

Скопируйте этот файл в

`/wp-content/themes/ваша-тема/woocommerce/order/order-details-item.php`

и отредактируйте так, как вам нужно.

Comment: я не силен в php, только учусь. Не могли бы более подробней рассказать как добыть эту злощасную фотку

Answer (score 0):

В файл order-details.php добавить это:

```
<th class="product-thumb"><?php _e( 'Image', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

В файл order-details-item.php добавить это:

```
<td class="product-thumb">
    <?php $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($item['product_id'], 'shop_catalog'); ?>
    <?php
        if(!empty($thumb)) {
           echo "<img src='{$thumb}'/>";
        }
    ?>
</td>
```